# How to apply a filter to a group of records in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of clients with purchases in different category lines. I must query and get back those who have bought a particular line.

For instance:

> ```
> RUT_DV_LOCAL    NAME        DESC_LINEA
> 10006919_9_1    CURIQUEO        TRADICIONAL
> 10006919_9_1    CURIQUEO        REFRIGERADOS
> 10015983_K_3    NAVARRETE       CONFITES
> 10015983_K_3    NAVARRETE       TRADICIONAL
> 10023883_7_3    EZPINOZA        CONFITES
> 10028999_7_1    ASTUDILLO       CONFITES
> 10028999_7_1    ASTUDILLO       REFRIGERADOS
> 10028999_7_1    ASTUDILLO       TRADICIONAL
> ```

The query I am looking for should give back those clients who have not bought 'CONFITES', having the following as a result:

> ```
> RUT_DV_LOCAL    NAME        DESC_LINEA
> 10006919_9_1    CURIQUEO        TRADICIONAL
> 10006919_9_1    CURIQUEO        REFRIGERADOS
> ```

Or at least just the client's name.

It must be a query and not an SP due to how it will be used down the road.

Thanks.

Comment: Muéstranos lo que has intentado hasta ahora para poder ayudarte.

Comment: me resulta gracioso ver una pregúnta en español :), en unos momentos la edito, si no hay problemas con eso

Comment: La tabla del Ejemplo es el Resultado de la relación entre una tabla con Clientes y otra con las Linea de Productos que ha comprado.

En la tabla de clientes cada cliente tiene un registro unico

Comment: Can somebody who speaks Spanish translate this? Given what I see however I have a feeling it is only going to lead to more questions as this post looks like it is lacking clarity.

Comment: @DamianLattenero me harías un gran favor al traducirlo. Gracias.

Comment: I can translate it, but @user2446129 needs to understand that he must take a crack at it first, before we can help him.

Comment: I translated it. It's awaiting peer review.

Comment: @user2446129. Some helps here: First, when you ask a question in this site, even if your english is so so bad (mine is horrible), you must try, there is another community like this for Spanish speakers like us.
 Second, this site is about helping people, but if the people first shows their work. So PLEASE ADD YOUR WORK SO FAR! Is the most important if you want people to help :). Two of us just translates your post for you THIS TIME! so please, for the future, you know how it works, also for future question see: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So like `select * from table where RUT_DV_LOCAL not in (select RUT_DV_LOCAL from table where  DESC_LINEA = 'CONFITES')`? I'm confused like @SeanLange

Comment: @scsimon I feel bad for you that are as confused as I am. :)

Comment: @scsimon your query works perfectly. Thanks, How do I put your answer as the solution?

Comment: @Marcelo SQLZim gave a good solution you can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `not exists()`:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.rut_dv_local = t.rut_dv_local
    and i.desc_line = 'CONFITES'
  )
```

---

Using `not exists()` with your joins:

```
select 
    rut_dv_local
  , nombre
  , desc_linea
from clientes c
  inner join linea l
    on c.id_cliente = l.id_cliente
where not exists (
  select 1
  from linea il 
  where il.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
    and il.desc_line = 'CONFITES'
  )
```

Comment: This does the same thing Marcelo so just accepted this one 

Comment: I'm using this query 

SELECT RUT_DV_LOCAL,NOMBRE,DESC_LINEA FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN LINEA L ON C.ID_CLIENTE=L.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE RUT_DV_LOCAL NOT IN (SELECT RUT_DV_LOCAL FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN LINEA L ON C.ID_CLIENTE=L.ID_CLIENTE WHERE DESC_LINEA = 'CONFITES')

could you help me to change 'NOT IN' to 'NOT EXISTS

Comment: @Marcelo I have updated my answer to show how to convert your `not in()` to `not exists()` with your joins.